# How many ways to develop outlook add in?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I found some ways below.
1. Add-in Express
2. VSTO 
3. unmanaged c++

I'm not sure is this right? 
And which way can compile only a dll without any dependency.
Using outlook add in, could I get the drag attachment event?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You will be surprised but there is only one way for developing Office COM add-ins - implement the [IDTExtensibility2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility.idtextensibility2.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) interaface. All the paths you mentioned follow this pattern and have their own pros and cons.

You can use managed programming languages for developing an add-in as well (C# or VB.NET). C++ is not required. Erlier VS versions had a template for that called "shared COM add-in". VSTO and Add-in Express provides shims (loaders) that create a new Application domain to run your add-in code in isolation from other add-ins. It is up to you which framework to use, or just not to use any.